# Opus decode parameters

Tags: codec, rfc, opus

According to [RFC7587](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7587.txt), in an RTP packet with following parameters, what is the Opus sampling rate? 48000 or 16000?

what does rtpmap mean?

```
m=audio 54312 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:101 maxplaybackrate=16000;
```

Answer (score 1):

The RTP sampling frequency is 48k , for timestamp calculation.

Audio Sampling frequency of the Audio decoder Playback/Render - 16K

maxplaybackrate:  a hint about the **maximum output sampling rate that
      the receiver is capable of rendering in Hz**.  The decoder MUST be
      capable of decoding any audio bandwidth, but, due to hardware
      limitations, only signals up to the specified sampling rate can be
      played back.  Sending signals with higher audio bandwidth results
      in higher than necessary network usage and encoding complexity, so
      an encoder SHOULD NOT encode frequencies above the audio bandwidth
      specified by maxplaybackrate.  This parameter can take any value
      between 8000 and 48000, although commonly the value will match one
      of the Opus bandwidths (Table 1).  By default, the receiver is
      assumed to have no limitations, i.e., 48000.

Comment: I use Zoiper to generate an RTP with opus payload type. I set sampling rate to 16000 and I can see above parameters in generated pcap file, but when I want to decode payload content, I use 48000 to sampling rate and 2 for number of channels. The audio file has been decoded correctly !!!! why?

Comment: Can you share few packets of the generated pcap ( to check the payload ) , if possible add the decoder logs.